# Отправлять на телефон сигнал о вызове

Tags: android, алгоритм

Хочу реализовать следующее:
На сайте есть поле обратного звонка. Необходимо, чтобы при отправке, на мой андроид-смартфон уходил сигнал и телефон начинал сразу вызов.
Как это реализовать, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: настроить пуш уведомление на сайте, они будут слаться тебе на телефон, а там уже принимай решение..

Comment: push-уведомления приходят в виде сообщений. Как заставить их звонить?